# Empty textbox in grid showing square brackets

Tags: html, gridview

We have a scenario wherein we have a editable gridview. Users enter data and submit. On submission we send the grid data as html in an email. The issue we are facing is that if a textbox is left empty it shows [    ] square brackets. These look very annoying. Kindly see screenshot the last bottom box is highlighted in red.

Kindly let know how we can make that square brackets gp away / donot show up.[image]

Comment: may be show us the HTML of the textbox ?

Comment: The html of the td in which textbox gets rendered is;                           <td width="8%" style="width:8.0%; padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
<p class="x_MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:7.5pt; font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;">[&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;] </span></p>
</td>

Comment: your HTML has this ? `[&nb‌​sp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp‌​;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&‌​nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;] ` Enclose the code within the `` please

Comment: Hi Nikhil, thank you for the reply. Is it that you mean to say tht we need to set ' i.e. single quote below [ and after ].                Kindly confirm

Comment: Hmm .. i Just wanted to have the exact code in your HTML file responsible for that textbox  generation & no not single quote but the **tilde** ("`") symbol, just below the ESC key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed to update the post for the answer. This issue happens when we are developing Visual Web part in SharePoint. And the Column type is Multiple Lines of text with option set to 'Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)'. Set it to 'Plain Text' and the boxes will go away.